# Extract jsonb fields as rows

Tags: postgresql

I have a table
users
name: varchar(20)
data:jsonb

Records look something like this

```
adam, {"car": "chevvy", "fruit": "apple"}
john, {"car": "toyota", "fruit": "orange"}
```

I want to extract all the fields like this

```
name.    |.type      |.  value
adam.      car         chevrolet
adam.      fruit       apple
john.      car       toyota
john.      car       orange
```

Comment: Did you try `jsonb_each`?

Comment: i couldn't figure out how to use it with a table

Comment: Please show us your attempt though so that we can help you figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example you can do:

```
SELECT name, d.key AS type, d.value
  FROM users u,
       JSONB_EACH_TEXT(u.data) AS d
;
```

output:

```
 name | type  | value  
------+-------+--------
 adam | car   | chevvy
 adam | fruit | apple
 john | car   | toyota
 john | fruit | orange
(4 rows)
```

There are good explanations here [PostgreSQL - jsonb_each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28857633/postgresql-jsonb-each)

Comment: Thank you. this is precisely what i was looking for'